# PHP code in .gif exploit

Tags: php, security, gif, exploit

I need to know how to generate a GIF with php code inside, or how to modify a gif to add this so that I can perform a test on our avatar upload plugin in wordpress - I just want to ensure it is secure. Or if someone has a test image already, which I can open to see the code or modify?

Comment: That's not a good way to prevent exploits. Rather than that, check how you include (ie. a get param with filename to include is not best practice) and make sure user input is properly validated. Then you don't have to (and you can't, really) check everything a user may upload.

Answer (score 1):

In an [LFI to RCE exploit](http://andiwijaya.wordpress.com/2009/10/24/lfi-to-rce-exploit-with-perl-script/) you add a meta tag that contains you're php code.  When the binary is included PHP will look for `<?php ?>` and execute the code inside of it.